# wordpress　musicプレイヤーの長さを変更したい。

Tags: wordpress, mp3

いつもお世話になっております。
現在、wordpressでサイトを作成中です。

下図の音源再生部分のwidthを変更したいのですが、どこのファイルで管理されていますでしょうか？

実際の画面
[image: 実際の画面]

ソース
[image: ソース]

ソースがみずらくて申し訳ございません。
テーマの種類はreliaになります。
よろしくお願いします。
element.styleを50%にすると目的どおり黒のバーの部分が半分になるのですが。。。

Answer (score 0):

お使いのテーマファイルのCSSにて`.mejs-container`に対して`width`を指定してはいかがですか？